# How to pass dataframe as an argument to mrsdeploy::publishService through curl POST?

Tags: curl, post, dockerfile, microsoft-r, deployr

I am trying to provide a R function as a web service for which I am using https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mlserver/2018/07/26/dockerizing-r-and-python-web-services/ as a reference.

I changed my function accordingly so that it should accept a dataframe.
I want to consume the web service through curl. How do I pass a dataframe to publishService function through curl?

I tried send the dataframe as a JSON so that curl POST should accept it as a string, but it isn't accepting.

```
library(mrsdeploy)
library(jsonlite)
manualTransmission <- function(hp, wt) { 
     hp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(hp)
     wt <- jsonlite::fromJSON(wt)
     c(hp[1,1],wt[1,1]) 
}
remoteLogin("http://localhost:12800", username = "admin", password = 
"Microsoft@2018", session = FALSE)
api <- publishService("ManualTransmissionService", code = 
manualTransmission, inputs = list(hp = "character", wt = "character"), 
outputs = list(answer = "vector"), v = "1.0.0")
```

The command:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer <accesstoken>" --request POST --data "{\"hp\": \"[{\"hp_col\": 5}]\",\"wt\": \"[{\"wt_col\": 5}]\"}" http://localhost:12800/api/ManualTransmissionService/1.0.0
```

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: > Content-Length: 49
>
* upload completely sent off: 49 out of 49 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 05:55:20 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Server: Kestrel
< Content-Length: 158
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< x-ms-request-id: 9ac57d0c-c852-46ab-9642-d3bc853f38b8
<
{"Link":"https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830136","Message":"Number of parameter mismatch. Expected: 2, Actual: 0","ExceptionType":"ArgumentException"}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact